# Content not moving around wrapper div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to structure a page such that there's a horizontal navigation bar at the top that all the other content on the page starts under (the navigation bar is fixed at the top, but the content isn't necessarily), and a side bar that all content should start to the right of (which is fixed at the left).

Here's a link to the jsfiddle, showing what I've tried: https://jsfiddle.net/o5p8yuvx/5/.

This doesn't work as intended however. The content starts under `topbar` but not to the right of `sidebar` (I've commented out `sidebar` to show that it sits under `topbar`; taking it out of the comment block will illustrate that it does not sit to the right of `sidebar`). I want `arbitrary text` outside both wrappers to sit in the empty part of the page that is not occupied by either bar (the big white space under `topbar` and to the right of `sidebar`), but currently it just sits underneath `topbar`. Since they're both wrappers, why is it only sitting under `topbar`, not sitting under `topbar` *and* sitting right of `sidebar`?

This is just an example however; other divs with content in them cause the same issue. How do I make all further content sit outside the bars, just like `sidebar` sits under `topbar`?

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please, not on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best to create a new `<div>` specifically for the content:

```
<div class="content">
  arbitrary text
</div>
```

Then, you can position the `<div>`, so that it fills the remaining space:

```
.content {
  margin: 0 0 0 300px;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.topwrapper {
  height: 60px;
}

.sidewrapper {
  width: 300px;
}

.topbar {
  background-color: grey;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0;
}

.topbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.topbar li {
  color: blue;
}

.topbar a:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.sidebar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.sidebar li {
  color: blue;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

.content {
  margin: 0 0 0 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Webpage</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="topwrapper">
    <div class="topbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a style="float: left">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a style="float: left">Link 2</a></li>
        <li>
          <p style="float: right">Welcome</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidewrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li><a>Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a>Link 4</a></li>
        <li>
          <p>Welcome</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    arbitrary text
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**I have also provided a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Zeraora/odj4bfgt/).**

---

*If you want your code to be semantically correct, you can use `<main>` instead of `<div class="content">`, then change your css to...*

```
main {
  margin: 0 0 0 300px;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.topwrapper {
  height: 60px;
}

.sidewrapper {
  width: 300px;
}

.topbar {
  background-color: grey;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0;
}

.topbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.topbar li {
  color: blue;
}

.topbar a:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.sidebar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.sidebar li {
  color: blue;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

main {
  margin: 0 0 0 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Webpage</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="topwrapper">
    <div class="topbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a style="float: left">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a style="float: left">Link 2</a></li>
        <li>
          <p style="float: right">Welcome</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidewrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li><a>Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a>Link 4</a></li>
        <li>
          <p>Welcome</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <main>
    arbitrary text
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this requies the `content` div to be fixed though. Is it possible to do this without making it fixed?

Comment: because before the original jsfiddle was edited, my answer was the correct one. see the comments on my answer

Comment: @JeremyLucas I know, I was watching. But your answer was accepted after the jsfiddle was changed, which confused me, probably because of your answer in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using 2 fixed properties, you will need to declare how far from the top to set the sidebar. You can fix this with 1 line in your css to say how far from the top of the parent container you want your div to be:

```
.sidebar {
  ...
  top: 60px;
}
```

I used `60px` because that is the size of your topbar. If the top bar changes, you can adjust the sidebar location accordingly. Here's an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wy09p51x/)

The browser defaults to `top: auto` so that the browser dictates where these items should be, even if it they are wrapped like you have it.

> If position: absolute; or position: fixed; - the top property sets the top edge of an element to a unit above/below the top edge of its nearest positioned ancestor.

Because of this, the css starts looking above to the next "positioned ancestor" and uses this as a reference of where the top should be

[Top references](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_top.asp)

Comment: sorry; I posted the wrong link in the original question. Could you take a look again?

Comment: `arbitrary text` still isn't showing though. How do I position this right of `sidebar`?

Comment: There are a few ways to do this. The easiest would to just wrap your arbitrary text with a container div and then set a `margin-left` equal to the width of your sidebar so `margin-left: 300px;` in your case. You could also do: `left: 300px` . Anything you want in the "white space" will go inside that `container` main content div. Here is updated of this. https://jsfiddle.net/0a3r9ckm/

Comment: Why does `float: left` not work in this case (when applied to `sidebar`) to achieve the same result?

Comment: This is due to the positioning of the fixed sidebar. Float is made and used to wrap text around items, but not necessarily force things to one side or the other (which is why many people rarely use float except to right-align items or wrap text around other items). The fixed positioning tells the browser no matter what it needs to be in the same spot, so you can't float any text afterwards. Css-Tricks has a pretty good article that can explain better than me too, let me know if you find what you're looking for https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: I see, was just curious why that was the case. Thank you

Comment: No problem :) Good luck!